# Prevent user from removing object properties but allow adding new ones

Tags: javascript

I have a an Object

```js
var a = {
    "somekey": "somevalue"
};
```

I want the user to have the option to extend this object but not delete the existing properties, like the Object.preventExtensions() but the opposite.
How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) for that.

As you can see both objects can be extended but deleting a property is simply ignored.

```js
const obj = {answer: 42};
const obj_proxy = new Proxy(obj, {
  deleteProperty(target, prop) {
    console.log(`delete "${prop}": not allowed`);
    // do nothing else
  }
});


delete obj_proxy.answer;
obj_proxy.another_answer = 42;

console.log(`obj -> ${JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2)}`);
console.log(`obj_proxy -> ${JSON.stringify(obj_proxy, null, 2)}`)
```

Comment: Now if I use it on a class with private members I can't access the members.
The goal is to have a base class with extensible properties but prevent the user from changing the properties in the base class

Comment: I achieved this by adding dynamic getter